# QString arg() printing restriction?

Tags: qt, qstring

I have probably missed something important on `QString` argument manipulation.

Can't find the reason why just str2 gives valid result. I've found few examples which are written in manner str1 so I guess it should work. Thanks.

```
QString str1 = QString("%1");
str1.arg("help");
qDebug() << QString("str1 - ") + str1;

QString str2 = QString("%1").arg("help");
qDebug() << QString("str2 - ") + str2;
```

Results in:

```
"str1 - %1" 
"str2 - help"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to assign the value of arg()

so use the returned value instead

e.g.

```
QString str1 = QString("%1");
str1 =str1.arg("help");
qDebug() << QString("str1 - ") + str1;
```

Comment: arg doesn't modify string. It uses string as pattern to construct new one

Comment: I see. Of course. Thanks. The reference help confuse me. The example for "QString QString::arg ( const QString & a1, const QString & a2 )" is not clear enough I guess.

Comment: Whats unclear in `QString status = QString("Processing file %1 of %2: %3")
                     .arg(i).arg(total).arg(fileName);` and in `Returns a copy of this string with the lowest numbered place marker replaced by string`

Comment: I meant the second one: QString str;
 str = "%1 %2";

 str.arg("%1f", "Hello");        // returns "%1f Hello"
 str.arg("%1f").arg("Hello");    // returns "Hellof %2"

Answer (score 0):

you answerd yourself in your example.

```
QString str1 = QString("%1");  // creates str1 with value "%1"
str1.arg("help");              // returns a string with `help` and the result is lost. 
qDebug() << QString("str1 - ") + str1;  // print "str1 - %1" because str1 still have "%1"

QString str2 = QString("%1").arg("help"); // creates str2 with value !help": given by returned value of `arg` that takes a string with value "%1" and substitutes "help".
qDebug() << QString("str2 - ") + str2; // now you are printing "str2 - help"
```

if you see documentation [Qstring:arg](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qstring.html#arg-2) you ll see that if you call `qstring("%1").arg("help")` you are calling `QString QString::arg ( const QString & a, int fieldWidth = 0, const QChar & fillChar = QLatin1Char( ' ' ) ) const`